# Сортировка в Virtuemart 2

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Как сделать, чтобы товары, которых нет в наличии, были внизу, а те, что в наличии, были наверху?

Answer (score 1):

В запросе SELECT используйте `ORDER BY product_availability DESC` (если мы говорим про таблицу #__virtuemart_products)